# How does VSCode's Python Extension handle a missing .env file?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-extensions

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue with VSCode's [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) loading the wrong version of Python and I'd like to rule out incorrect environment variables being an issue.

In the Python Extension's settings there is the following option:

[image: Python: Env File option in VSCode's Python extension settings.]

My workspace doesn't contain a `./env` file. What will VSCode's Python extension default to in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the official VSCode documentation on [Environment Variable Definition Files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file). I think the following section is relevant to your question:

[image: VSCode's Environment Variable Definition file section.]

As you can see, the `.env` file is there to set the value of any **pre-existing environment variables**.

If the file existed but had no key-value pairs in it then the environment variables would be unchanged from the system's own definitions.

Therefore, if `.env` doesn't exist, the environment variables will be defined by your system. This is the default behaviour.